# Modules Support for Alloy Titanium Projects

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I've been developing for a long time in Titanium. I have a simple question that I couldn't find in documentation, are any modules developed for Titanium compatible with Alloy projects?

I mean most of my projects are in Classic Titanium, my question is related to whether I convert this projects to Alloy, the modules that I'm using will still be working?

Otherwise, I will keep using Classic instead of Alloy, because I depend a lot of modules on my projects to fulfill clients requirements.

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alloy is just a different way of structuring your code, doesn't change anything for modules. You won't have a problem using them.

Comment: Thank's I will migrate then.